# Binning data by order with selected bin size

Tags: r

I have a vector of values that I want to order by value in descending order, then bin in bins of size 100, with the final bin containing all of the remaining values.

```
#generate random data
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(8366)

#In descending order
y <- x[order(-x)]
```

Now I have used `cut` to bin by value before, but I want the bins to be of finite size. So the first bin will have the first 100 values in y, the second bin the next hundred etc until I have ten bins, with the final bin containing all of the remaining values. I am not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will return the bins as a list:

```
mylist <- split(y, c(rep(1:9, each = 100), rep(10, 8366 - 900)))
```

The first 9 elements contain 100 records each and the rest are stored in the 10th element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am actually looking for only ten bins in total. So the last bin wil end up having the majority of the data whilst the other nine bins only have 100 values each.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "bin". Do you want to summarize each 100 values in some way? For example, sum them? If so, here's one solution:

```
#generate random data
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(8836)

n <- ceiling(length(x)/100) * 100
y <- rep(0, n)

#In descending order
y[1:length(x)] <- x[order(-x)]

X <- matrix(y, nrow = , ncol = 100, byrow = T) 
apply(X, 2, sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` :

```
res <- cut(y,c(rev(y)[seq(1,901,100)],Inf),right = F)
table(res)
# res
# [-3.67,-2.33) [-2.33,-2.05) [-2.05,-1.87) [-1.87,-1.72)  [-1.72,-1.6) 
#           100           100           100           100           100 
#   [-1.6,-1.5)  [-1.5,-1.41) [-1.41,-1.34) [-1.34,-1.27)   [-1.27,Inf) 
#           100           100           100           100          7466
```